# Magento and Review (5 star rating- delete extra bullets)

Tags: magento-1.7

Facing a problem, in the review section I have 5 stars, but there are additiona bullets. These blank bullets also show in the admin panel  in the review section when someone places a review. **Any idea how to remove the remaining 5 bullets?**

[image]

Path 
**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/form.phtm**

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAction() ?>" method="post" id="review-form">
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_fields_before')?>
        <h3><?php echo $this->__("You're reviewing:"); ?> <span><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductInfo()->getName()) ?></span></h3>
        <?php if( $this->getRatings() && $this->getRatings()->getSize()): ?>
            <h4><?php echo $this->__('How do you rate this product?') ?> <em class="required">*</em></h4>
            <span id="input-message-box"></span>
            <table class="data-table" id="product-review-table">
                <col />
                <col width="1" />
                <col width="1" />
                <col width="1" />
                <col width="1" />
                <col width="1" />
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('1 star') ?></span></th>
                        <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('2 stars') ?></span></th>
                        <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('3 stars') ?></span></th>
                        <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('4 stars') ?></span></th>
                        <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('5 stars') ?></span></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                    <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                        <td class="value"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="validate_rating" class="validate-rating" value="" />
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-review-table')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: show your code, and file paths

Comment: @Nickool Updated information, please take a look.

Comment: are you sure it is reading the base folder? don't you have the same under your theme?

Comment: Catalog->reviews and rating, Manage rating what do you have?

Comment: @Nickool Yeah  I look at theme file and they dont contain this file. Temporary I added h><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('5 stars') ?></span></th> for star 6 7 8 9 10, so teh rating system doesnt look half empty like on screenshot I Posted.. but I would like to remove the remainign 5 stars.

Comment: good practice is you have the files under your theme and not touch your base folder. design fallback.

Comment: @Nickool in Manage Rating I  have Price, Quality and Value... They are all Visible in Default Store View...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46830/discussion-between-icon-and-nickool).

Comment: @Icon as long as you share the result here, we'd all be happy